# How to intentionally create a core dump from a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm wanting to disable core dumps for a process that is ran inside of a docker container. The process is being started from a bash script that is the entry point for the container. My plan is to add the `ulimit -c 0` command to the bash script to disable core dumps for the process.

In order to test and see if this would work, I created the below bash script which should create a sleep job and then kills it to create a core dump. The idea is that after I know that this creates a core dump, I would add `ulimit -c 0` to the script to see if it prevents the dump. My problem is that the process is not being killed.

```
#!/bin/bash

ulimit -c

sleep 1000&

jobs

kill -3 %1

jobs
```

The output that I get is below

```
sh-4.2# bash test.sh 
unlimited
[1]+  Running                 sleep 1000 &
[1]+  Running                 sleep 1000 &
```

The job is still running and no core dump is produced. When I run these one by one on the command line, it successfully kills the job and creates a core dump.

What is wrong with my script?

Comment: I don't know whether %1 works in a non-interactive bash, but why don't you do a `kill -3 $!` and remove the `jobs` commands?

Comment: @user1934428 I get the following output 

`sh-4.2# bash test.sh `
`unlimited`
`test.sh: line 7: kill: %!: no such job`

Comment: The suggestion was to kill `$!` (the PID of the most recent process started in the background).  `%!` is not a valid job specification.  Killing by PID runs the risk of killing the wrong process (if the original process has exited and the PID has been reused) so it's generally best to kill by job specification.

Comment: @JamesSullivan : `%!` does not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) states:

> When job control is not in effect, asynchronous commands ignore SIGINT and SIGQUIT ...

[Job control](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Job-Control) is on by default for interactive shells and off by default for non-interactive shells.  That explains the difference that you see in the handling of SIGQUIT signals by background/asynchronous processes.

One option for fixing the problem is to explicitly turn on job control in the program.  Put `set -o monitor` (or, equivalently, `set -m`) close to the start of the code.

Another option is to use a different signal to trigger the core dump.  For example, try `kill -ABRT %1`.